# How to render a select tag with an option marked as selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :category %><br />
  <%= select_tag "category", options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, "id", "name"), :prompt => "Select something" %>
  <% if not @category_id.nil? %>
    <script>  
    $("#category option").each(function(){
      if ( this.value == <%= @category_id %> )
        this.selected = true;
    });                    
    </script>              
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I wanna make the category `<select>` tag have the right value (`@category_id`).

I try adding some script to category.js.coffee, but I found I can't pass the @category_id to the coffee file. So the script is inline.

I don't know any other ways to solve the problem. *I just think my code is ugly.*

Can anybody have any other solutions about my question.
If you were me, which method will you use. Thx.

Regards,
Rails newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to render one of the options as pre-selected without javascript. Try `options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, "id", "name", @category_id)`.